# How to pass the details of an AWS instance to a jenkins job, for the job to ssh and execute in the instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, automation

I am trying to move the execution of automated scripts(Jenkins jobs) in my organization from local server to AWS. I have  a Jenkins job to bring up an ec2 instance from the snapshot.  The instance which I have brought up consists of 5 user profiles, a total of 5 automation  jobs can login to the instance and execute their scripts.

My problem is, the instance I'm bringing up will be terminated once the jobs have been executed(Since we execute those scripts around 3 to 4 times in a month). So each time, I bring up an instance , it will have different IP address, which needs to be passed to the other Jenkins jobs, for the jobs to login into the instance and execute the scripts. My questions is as follows.

How to pass the details of the instance to the jenkins , making the process dynamic?
Are there any other ways , by which this problem can be solved(any solution which you might have implemented at your organisation)?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that you want to configure in your Jenkins in order to pass parameters to your jobs.

1. Enable "Trigger build remotely" in the Build Triggers. Read more about it [here](https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2015/10/triggering-jenkins-builds-by-url/).
2. Enable "This project is parameterized" and configure your parameters. Read more about it [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build).

Now you can start your jobs remotely and pass parameters in your URI like so:

`http://server/job/myjob/buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN&PARAMETER=Value`

this is also explained in the second link.

Then all thats left to do is add the parameter to your command line args for your script. So if you use Execute Shell build step it would look like this:

`python /path/to/file/scripit.py --some_arg ${PARAMETER}`